# Select a row from table and diplay name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two entities, `Project` and `Domain`. Project `has_many` Domains and Domain `belongs_to` Project, but the `domain_id` is stored into Project table.

In rails c I tried

`p = Project.first`   `d = Domain.where(id: p.domain_id)`

And I got

`Domain Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "domains".* FROM "domains" WHERE "domains"."id" = 1
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Domain id: 1, name: "alex.com", created_at: ...">]>`

When I tried

`d.name` => the result was 'Domain' instead of alex.com

`2.0.0-p247 :007 > d.name
 => "Domain"`

Why is this happening?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's a relation `ActiveRecord::Relation` so a transparent array of results. try calling `first` on it to get to the actual object.